# Why use destructuring here?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I asked this question on The Odin Project where I encountered it and was directed to research destructuring, which I did. I understand what is happening but I'm at a loss as to why it is being done this way. Simply using raw variable names with no destructuring braces gets the same result (see my jfiddle link where I removed the destructuring and got the same result). I find it hard to learn something when I'm directed to use more code, typing, and complexity to achieve the same outcome. what benefit is received here by using `return {sayName}` in const Person and `const {sayName} = Person(name)` in const Nerd? I used `return sayName` and `const sayName` in the jfiddle and got the same result.

Original code:

```
const Person = (name) => {
  const sayName = () => console.log(`my name is ${name}`)
  return {sayName}
}

const Nerd = (name) => {
  // simply create a person and pull out the sayName function with destructuring assignment syntax!
  const {sayName} = Person(name)
  const doSomethingNerdy = () => console.log('nerd stuff')
  return {sayName, doSomethingNerdy}
}

const jeff = Nerd('jeff')

jeff.sayName() //my name is jeff
jeff.doSomethingNerdy() // nerd stuff
```

[jfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/PrinceCorwin/kjshp3xc/)

```
const Person = (name) => {
  const sayName = () => console.log(`my name is ${name}`)
  return sayName
}

const Nerd = (name) => {
  // simply create a person and pull out the sayName function with destructuring assignment syntax!
  const sayName = Person(name)
  const doSomethingNerdy = () => console.log('nerd stuff')
  return {sayName, doSomethingNerdy}
}

const jeff = Nerd('jeff')

jeff.sayName() //my name is jeff
jeff.doSomethingNerdy() // nerd stuff
```

Comment: "The Odin Project" seems to be some teaching site. I'm not sure how many, if any, users around here are familiar with their curriculum. My best guess is that they want to introduce the concept now, so they can build upon it in later teaching materials. But I really can't say. Not sure if anybody can.

Comment: When you use a powerful feature like destructuring for something simple, it often masks how useful the feature is. When you go on to use it where it _should_ be used, it'll make perfect sense

Comment: Well, one thing that this kinda looks like is inheritance. You can have `Person`s and you can have `Nerd`s and everyone has a `sayName()` function but only nerds have a `doSomethingNerdy()` function... Although this is a rather weird way to do inheritance too.

Comment: @Jamiec Exactly! I guess my point is that my mind instantly disregards the concept because it is completely pointless here. This wasn't really a lesson on destructuring... they just threw it in out of nowhere and didn't expand on it in following exercises. I've used destructuring before but don't get the use here. Bad teaching practice if you ask me. Oh well. I guess I'll just let it go.

Comment: My guess is that this is supposed to be an example of destructuring, but it looked better in the author's head. You're right, it doesn't make sense here. There are many good use cases for destructuring, but this is not one of them.

Comment: In the orginal code, it is a bad example.You should better not use destructuring since you return only one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus is that this is a bad example for destructuring, but I've gone too far deep and will still attempt to make sense of it.

By using destructuring, it becomes possible to add additional functions to `Person`.

For example, Person needs to jump:

```
const Person = (name) => {
  const sayName = () => console.log(`my name is ${name}`)

  const jump = () => console.log('I jumped') // new feature

  return {sayName, jump} // jump can inserted into the object here and used externally
}
```

Then, as pointed out in the comments, a much better way to pass Person into Nerd would be to:

```
const Nerd = (name) => {
  // simply create a person and pull out the sayName function with destructuring assignment syntax!
  const doSomethingNerdy = () => console.log('nerd stuff')
  return {...Person(name) , doSomethingNerdy}
}
```

Before finally, Nerd can be destructured, and all the functions inside Person and Nerd can be used.

I suppose that's what they're trying to get at.

Comment: that's all I can figure also. The problem is that they never state this as the reason. The following lessons don't expand on this codeblock. Thanks for the comment

Comment: "*By using destructuring, it becomes possible to add additional functions to Person*" There is no need to *destructure* in order to get the same behaviour. What you showed is just creating an object literal - there is basically no relation to the destructuring assignment aside from the syntax being similar as it's designed to be mirrored.

Comment: Line 1, you do not add additional functions to Person.

Comment: "*`Nerd` can then destructure `Person` and use `sayName` and `jump`*" it could also *not* do this but instead return `{...Person(name), doSomethingNerdy }` without destructuring anything.